# Extract strings from a file and append strings to execute it on linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, grep

I have a file which has a following syntax:

example.file

```
...
    packageEARTH {
        ...
    }
    packageMARS {
        ...
    }
    packageVENUS {
        ...
    }
...
```

I usually use an IDE to convert it into a string like this:

`./builder makepackageVENUSMain ; ./builder makepackageVENUSMain ; ./builder makepackageVENUSMain` and paste it in the terminal for building.

I want to automate this process. Also, is it possible to add a command every 30 lines like this:

`./builder clearSpace; ./builder makepackageVENUSMain ...30x makepackge ... ./builder clearSpace; ... 30xmakepackage ... ./builder clearSpace;  ...27x makepackage;`

Basically I want to get all the strings from the file, then run a command on a modified string.

How should I approach this?
Should I do this with a shell script using grep or can awk be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with awk.

Command

```
awk '{print  $0; if ( $NF % 30 == 0){ print "echo your comment here"}}' lines.txt |bash
```

considering my input file lines.txt is a list of commands (echo to easiness)

```
echo line 1
echo line 2
echo line 3
echo line 4
echo line 5
echo line 6
echo line 7
echo line 8
echo line 9
echo line 10
echo line 11
echo line 12
echo line 13
echo line 14
echo line 15
echo line 16
echo line 17
echo line 18
echo line 19
echo line 20
echo line 21
echo line 22
echo line 23
echo line 24
echo line 25
echo line 26
echo line 27
echo line 28
echo line 29
echo line 30
echo line 31
echo line 32
echo line 33
echo line 34
echo line 35
echo line 36
echo line 37
echo line 38
echo line 39
echo line 40
echo line 41
echo line 42
echo line 43
echo line 44
echo line 45
echo line 46
echo line 47
echo line 48
echo line 49
echo line 50
echo line 51
echo line 52
echo line 53
echo line 54
echo line 55
echo line 56
echo line 57
echo line 58
echo line 59
echo line 60
echo line 61
echo line 62
echo line 63
echo line 64
echo line 65
echo line 66
echo line 67
```

Result

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
line 11
line 12
line 13
line 14
line 15
line 16
line 17
line 18
line 19
line 20
line 21
line 22
line 23
line 24
line 25
line 26
line 27
line 28
line 29
line 30
your comment here
line 31
line 32
line 33
line 34
line 35
line 36
line 37
line 38
line 39
line 40
line 41
line 42
line 43
line 44
line 45
line 46
line 47
line 48
line 49
line 50
line 51
line 52
line 53
line 54
line 55
line 56
line 57
line 58
line 59
line 60
your comment here
line 61
line 62
line 63
line 64
line 65
line 66
line 67
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Though this would not solve my query. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. My files have other text too, not just "echo line" lines. But I guess I could use grep and pipe that output to awk.

So that would be `grep -E '\bpackage' example.file`

Comment: How do I append string in front and at the end of the word?